# Does the infimum norm over norms of Hilbert Spaces induce an inner product?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

#### The question

I have a family of Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Spaces $\mathcal{B}$. A Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space (RKHS) $H_k$ is a Hilbert Space together with a positive semi-definite function $k$ of which every function $f\in H_k$ can be written like $f(x)=\int k(y,x)f(y)dy$. This function $k$ uniquely defines the RKHS. Consider the kernel $k_\pi$ given by
\begin{align*}
     k_\pi(x,y) := \mathbb{E}_{w\sim\pi}[\sigma(w^Tx)\sigma(w^Ty)] = \int \sigma(w^Tx)\sigma(w^Ty)\pi(dw)
\end{align*}
where $\pi$ is some probability distribution and $\sigma(x) = \max(0,x)$. If we take the union over all the possible probability distribution $\pi$, then we get
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{B} := \cup_\pi H_{k_\pi}
\end{align*}
This union is indicated by the letter $\mathcal{B}$, since it is commonly called the Barron Space.

Because of the specific choices for $k_\pi$ every function in $H_{k_\pi}$ can be written like
\begin{align*}
    f(x) = \int a(w)\sigma(w^Tx)\pi(dw)
\end{align*}
for some $a$. As a result we have that the norms of $H_{k_\pi}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are given by
\begin{align*}
    ||f||_{H_{k_\pi}} &= \int |a(w)|^2\pi(dw) \\
    ||f||_{\mathcal{B}} &= \inf_\pi ||f||_{H_{k_\pi}} \\
\end{align*}

I was wondering whether $\mathcal{B}$ is again a Hilbert Space. Since we have a norm, the simplest way to check this would be to check the parallelogram law. This states that if a space $X$ has a norm satisfying
\begin{equation}
    ||x+y||^2+||x-y||^2 \leq 2||x||^2+2||y||^2 \quad \forall x,y\in X
\end{equation}
So does $||\cdot||_\mathcal{B}$ satisfy the parallelogram law?

#### ... and my attempt at solving it

If both $f,g\in H_{k_{\pi_i}}$ for some $\pi_i$, then both $f,g\in\mathcal{B}$ and
\begin{align*}
    ||f+g||_\mathcal{B} &= ||f+g||_{H_{k_{\pi_i}}}  \\
    ||f-g||_\mathcal{B} &= ||f-g||_{H_{k_{\pi_i}}}  \\
    ||f||_\mathcal{B} &= ||f||_{H_{k_{\pi_i}}}  \\
    ||g||_\mathcal{B} &= ||g||_{H_{k_{\pi_i}}}  \\
\end{align*}
hence the parallellogram law is satisfied by virtue of $H_{k_{\pi_i}}$ being a Hilbert Space.

Now w.l.o.g. let $f\in H_{k_{\pi_0}},g\in H_{k_{\pi_1}}$ with $\pi_0$ and $\pi_1$ distinct. Then we know that
\begin{align*}
    ||f+g||_\mathcal{B} &= \inf_\pi ||f+g||_{H_{k_{\pi}}} \leq ||f+g||_{H_{k_{\pi_j}}} \quad j\in\{0,1\}   \\
    ||f-g||_\mathcal{B} &= \inf_\pi ||f-g||_{H_{k_{\pi}}} \leq ||f-g||_{H_{k_{\pi_j}}} \quad j\in\{0,1\}   \\
\end{align*}
Now we can write
\begin{align*}
    ||f+g||^2_\mathcal{B} + ||f-g||^2_\mathcal{B} 
        &\leq ||f-g||^2_{H_{k_{\pi_j}}}+||f-g||^2_{H_{k_{\pi_j}}} \\
        &= 2||f||^2_{H_{k_{\pi_j}}}+2||g||^2_{H_{k_{\pi_j}}} \\
\end{align*}
for $j\in\{0,1\}$. Taking $j=0$ gives
\begin{align*}
    ||f+g||^2_\mathcal{B} + ||f-g||^2_\mathcal{B} 
        &\leq 2||f||^2_{H_{k_{\pi_0}}}+2||g||^2_{H_{k_{\pi_0}}} \\
        &= 2||f||^2_\mathcal{B}+2||g||^2_{H_{k_{\pi_0}}} \\
        &\color{red}{\geq 2||f||^2_\mathcal{B}+2||g||^2_\mathcal{B}}
\end{align*}
whereas taking $j=1$ gives
\begin{align*}
    ||f+g||^2_\mathcal{B} + ||f-g||^2_\mathcal{B} 
        &\leq 2||f||^2_{H_{k_{\pi_0}}}+2||g||^2_{H_{k_{\pi_0}}} \\
        &= 2||f||^2_{H_{k_{\pi_1}}}+2||g||^2_\mathcal{B} \\
        &\color{red}{\geq 2||f||^2_\mathcal{B}+2||g||^2_\mathcal{B}}
\end{align*}
Both lines in red contradict the parallellogram law. Does this mean that $\mathcal{B}$ is no Hilbert Space? Or am I missing some step in my proof?